# How to send space " " as parameter value to oracle sql where clause through .net

Tags: .net, oracle

I am adding the parameter p_used as below

```
public Getdet (PKey key)
        {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.Append("SELECT  label ");
            sql.Append(" From table  ");
            sql.Append(" Where used = @p_usage");


            DbAccess mDb = ApplicationContext.CurrentDb;
            Getdet result = null;

            using (IDbCommand cmd = mDb.GetCommand(sql.ToString()))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                mDb.AddParameter(cmd, "p_used", " ");

                using (IDataReader rdr = mDb.ExecuteReader(cmd))
                {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            result = this.LoadThis(rdr);
                        }

                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

when the reader executes command, it will fetch rows when connected to mssql database from .net code but does not fetch reult when connected to oracle database from .net code.

Comment: _where @p_usage = " "_ is wrong. You cannot use a parameter to specify a field name. Please show a [MCVE] of your problem

Comment: @Steve, the left side of the equals operator does not necessarily have to be a field name. It may be any expression, including a literal substituted from parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle `"` double quotes are used to surround a case-sensitive column (or object) identifier. Single `'` quotes are used for text literals.

So, if you are intending to select from a column which has a single space character as its name like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( " " NUMBER );
INSERT INTO table_name ( " " ) VALUES ( 1 );
```

Then use:

```
select * from table_name where @p_usage = " ";
```

It you want to compare it to a text literal then you need to use:

```
select * from table_name where @p_usage = ' ';
```